# cannot run docker image with mounted folder

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a docker image with a folder from the host mounted to the docker image. I have a mac running on sierra. I want to mount '/Users/' folder form the host to the container path of 'code'. This is what I put in:

```
docker run -it -v /Users:code 7b9b13f7b9c0 latest
```

I got this error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec "/Users:code": Invalid volume destination path: 'code' mount path must be absolute..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all.  You must specify a full path for the `code` directory like this:

`-v /Users:/path/to/code`